# Composing Enumeratees in Enumerator

Tags: haskell, enumerator

*Disclaimer: this was asked recently on the haskell-cafe list. My apologies to anyone bothered by the double post.*

All of the iteratee-implementing packages that I know of (e.g. `iteratee`, `iterIO`, and `conduit`) define an enumeratee composition function, except for the `enumerator` package. This seems to me like a serious limitation, and yet it also seems relatively straightforward to implement:

```
import Data.Enumerator
import Data.Enumerator.Internal

(=$=) :: Monad m
      => Enumeratee a0 a1 m (Step a2 m b) -> Enumeratee a1 a2 m b
      -> Enumeratee a0 a2 m b
(=$=) e01 e12 step = Iteratee $ do
    step' <- runIteratee $ e12 step
    runIteratee . joinI $ e01 step'
```

Is there some gotcha here that I'm missing? Or some other reason for `enumerator` not to define enumeratee composition?

Comment: I've emailed the author/maintainer of [the enumerator package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/enumerator), John Millikin, linking him to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's now a new release (0.4.17) of `enumerator` that includes a `(=$=)` operator with the signature I gave above. I emailed the package's author and he makes a good case against including a lot of simplified operators (like `($=)`, `(=$)`, and now `(=$=)`) in the package.

Basically, the problem is that of handling left-over input. The `joinI` combinator

```
joinI :: Monad m => Iteratee a m (Step a' m b) -> Iteratee a m b
```

discards the left-over `Stream a'` that's yielded by the inner `Iteratee`. This is not a problem if one uses a style like

```
joinI (foo $$ (bar $$ baz))
```

where the left-over data is only discarded at the end of the computation. However, using the simplified operators results in multiple implicit joins and the left-over data becomes much harder to keep track of. If the iteratees being used are simple (i.e. they don't yield left-over data) then this is not a problem and the simplified operators make sense to use.